# How to silence "The feature name "router" does not exist in the state..." ngrx/router-store warning

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

When I add "@ngrx/router-store" to my project, it spams the app console in development mode and unit test results with the following message:

> The feature name "router" does not exist in the state, therefore createFeatureSelector cannot access it.  Be sure it is imported in a loaded module using StoreModule.forRoot('router', ...) or StoreModule.forFeature('router', ...).  If the default state is intended to be undefined, as is the case with router state, this development-only warning message can be ignored.

I tried to set `router` state property type to

```
router: null |  RouterReducerState<SerializedRouterStateSnapshot>
```

and initial state value to

```
router: null
```

but it clashes with `routerReducer` type, which only accepts

```
RouterReducerState<SerializedRouterStateSnapshot>
```

How do I disable this warning? I honestly find it rather annoying.

Comment: So it's not really a question but rather something you want to show, since you answered it ?

Comment: @Maryannah exactly, I couldn't find relevant questions on SO, but there were [similar unanswered questions in ngrx repo](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1897#issuecomment-535833183), so I found a solution and decided to share. I know this is encouraged on SE.

Comment: Sure, that was just to be sure, and make you state it so other users do not have to scratch their head finding a solution. Good for you then !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what helped me: do not use `createFeatureSelector` to create router feature selector, use `createSelector` instead.

```
export const routerState = createSelector((state: State) => state.router, value => value)
```

The issue happens because `createFeatureSelector` [logs a warning](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/c63941ce40368b7acea5816e0e7520b2c48f9245/modules/store/src/selector.ts#L610) if feature value equals to `undefined`. The code above is equivalent to original implementation, but without a log.

**Update:** [here's a PR](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/2163) that aims to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `default return` in your switch statement?

```
 default:
   return state;
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: In my case the console showed me this because in my reducer I didn't had a default return of the state, have you tried?

Comment: @Klaster_1 I have to agree with Tecayehuatl because I also forgot the default return in my reducer and got similar error hence I find myself here. I have voted up the answer as it is a legitimate answer to solve errors some of us are having troubles dealing with. This answer just saved my day ;-)

Answer (score -1):

try to select the router slice of state with a simple function

```
export const selectRouter = (state: State) => state.router;
```

because createFeatureSelector, hence the name, is used for selecting a slice of state added in a FEATURE module

```
StoreModule.forFeature('feature1', reducers)
```

in this case you should use createFeatureSelector

```
export const selectFeature1 = createFeatureSelector<State, Feature1State>('feature1');
```